# GNU find: test for file size greater/smaller-equal a certain size

Tags: linux, find

Is there a way with GNU find to find files with a size `>=` or `<=` a certain size? I have only found the `>`, `<`, `==` operators, e.g. `-size +1M`, `-size -1M`, `-size 1M`, respectively.

In [this](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/find-files-bigger-smaller-size/) blog, the author suggested a combination of multiple `-size` arguments as in `find . -type f -size +1M -size -2M`. However, this does not work for my find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2.

Comment: Are you saying that you want files that are 1048576 bytes or greater, but using "+1M" excludes files of exactly 1048576 bytes?

Comment: @AlexHowansky, I did not actually try that, but according to the documentation "+1M" means *more than* 1 MB.

Comment: Right -- my point being, why not just drop the count by a byte: "-size +1048575b"

Comment: @Alex: :-) right, right... but being able to say >=1M is arguably more comfortable.

Comment: Do you *really* need to know that one-byte difference? :)

Comment: It's about automation. Consider doing one thing with a set of files smaller than a certain size `s` and another thing with the set of files larger `s`. You would miss processing those files with a size equal to `s`.

Comment: [How can I find files that are bigger/smaller than x bytes?](http://superuser.com/q/204564/173513) on Super User.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since the operator `<=` is logically equivalent to `not >` (Not greater than), these 2 operators can be swapped with each other. In our example, to find files with size less than or equal to 1M, you can look for files not larger than 1M: `-not -size +1M`.

The same logic can be applied to `>=` using `not <`.

Comment: Ah, I was not aware of `-not`. This is elegant (`-a` / `-and`, as suggested by Pierre, also is).

Comment: This might help someone: bytes is not "b" as you would expect, 480 bytes is "-size 480c"

Comment: This (from [the `man` page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html)) is also quite relevant: _Bear in mind that the size is rounded up to the next unit. Therefore -size -1M is not equivalent to -size -1048576c. The former only matches empty files, the latter matches files from 0 to 1,048,575 bytes.`_

Answer (score 7):

the following command seems to work:

```
]$  find -version
find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2

find  ~ -type f -size '+1k' -a  -size '-3k' -exec ls -lah '{}' ';'
```